# Log4j2 2.17.0 Context Lookups in Property tags replacement

Tags: java, log4j2, mdc

We recently updated our version of Log4j2 to 2.17.0 due to the recent vulnerability.  However since the upgrade, certain context lookups no longer seem to work.  I read this article that states:

> Mitigations include applying the 2.17.0 patch and replacing Context Lookups like ${ctx:loginId} or $${ctx:loginId} with Thread Context Map patterns (%X, %mdc, or %MDC) in PatternLayout in the logging configuration.

This is an example of what we have currently:

```
<Property name="filename.trans_log">${sys:access.log.location}/${web:contextPath}_transaction_$${ctx:txLogRecordType}.log
</Property>
```

Added to the MDC in Java:

```
MDC.put("txLogRecordType", eventType);
```

Which is now producing logs looking like

```
meanwhileinhell_transaction_${ctx.txLogRecordType}_2022-01-27-16.log
```

As far as I'm aware you cannot add a PatternLayout to `Property` types, so can anyone tell me if there is a way, through configuration alone, that I can get this property to substitute?

Comment: `We recently updated our version of Log4j2 to 2.17.0 due to the recent vulnerability`. You're still vulnerable btw, at least to [some extent](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html). Not an answer to your question, sorry

Comment: have you found solution to this yet ?

Comment: @Anddo I raised an issue with Log4j2 on their Jira, and it seems that this has been fixed in what I'm assuming will be v.2.17.2.  If you take their latest snapshot release, it will be included.

Comment: I just found that out. Thank you for letting me know.